# Python: sending email with self-created server and self-defined temporary sender address

Tags: python, email

StackOverflow I need help with this project of mine.

So it's to test an existing sorting algorithm for a client's email (the algorithm is irrelevant),  to do this, I'm creating a program (would be best if it's written in Python, as that's the language that I'm most familiar with) that sends emails with different sender addresses and (at best different servers) I'd like to know if there's a way to send email with custom-created server(or domain if you call it) (like "@xyz.com", "@abc.co", "@hello.net",...etc.)

and is it possible to use creat temporary sender addresses? Like I'd only use these addresses to send email once and I don't care about receiving anything on this address. I would need around 20 domains and hundreds of address so it would be impossible to do if I have to sign up new address manually.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Here's](https://lifehacker.com/how-spammers-spoof-your-email-address-and-how-to-prote-1579478914) more about how to do this...and how to prevent this!

Comment: I think it is fairly easy to send a spoofed email. If you are in control of the receiving server you can actually receive it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html